# IMAP Oauth2 login not working even with the valid access token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, outlook, imap, azure-ad-msal

[GitHub source code] (https://github.com/lekhnath-parajuli/oauth2_imap_smtp_implementation.git)

I tried to authenticate with the generated token using

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -servername outlook.office365.com -crlf
```

but it only takes maximum 1024 characters, but the token i got was around 4k to 5k characters.
not sure if it's character length of the token that is causing the IMAP authentication issue or anything else. because the token received worked fine on Microsoft Graph api but not in IMAP server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uttam/Documents/work/fast-api/imap_synching/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 415, in oauth2_login
    return self._command_and_check("authenticate", mech, lambda x: auth_string)
  File "/Users/uttam/Documents/work/fast-api/imap_synching/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imapclient/imapclient.py", line 1738, in _command_and_check
    typ, data = meth(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/imaplib.py", line 444, in authenticate
    raise self.error(dat[-1].decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

so, someone please help me with this

Comment: Please provide more context so we can see the code you used, and the parameters you passed (you can redact the token), and how you got the token.  What scopes does it have? How old is the token?

Comment: i have attached the GitHub link above 

https://github.com/lekhnath-parajuli/oauth2_imap_smtp_implementation.git